# HTTP 404 ajax call on mvc controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404, jsonresult

Im trying to get some json data from an mvc controller action using an ajax call, but im getting a resource not found error and I cant see why.

my ajax call uses url.action

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetEdit", "Disclaimer")',
        data: { id: rowId },
```

and my disclaimer controller has this action method

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetEdit(int id)
    {
```

in the method I generate some json data and return it, but I get this error

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Disclaimer/GetEdit

just cant see why, must be something obvious im missing, can anyone help ?

Comment: its ok, ive sorted it, schoolby error, I had POST instead of GET as the type in the ajax call